# Linux: Where is package installed after installing from .bin

Tags: linux, fedora

Im a newbie to linux so please dont get annoyed with this basic question.
I searched internet about it but all i could find was the installation instructions.
Can someone tell me where is the program installed when installing from .bin file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's installed wherever the author of the .bin file programmed it to be installed. There's no standard location.

Comment: This may be considered [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **find** and **Xargs** commands for locate files that have been installed. You can use for instance find directory -nmin Number_of_minutes to see which files were modified in some directory in last Number_of_minutes. Xargs is a command "used to build and execute command lines". You can combine that twho command to list the files, as shown in [find and Xargs using](http://www.hcidata.info/find.htm), but you try it first in root directory or you can limit to /bin.